# Disable any user input using ReactQuill library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill, react-ace

I'm trying to use ReactQuill just to show some rich text that I have, and therefore I don't want that it can receive any input or typing from the user. Reason, I have another library (ReactAce), and ReactQuill is causing a bug that when I type the 'delete' key, it made the ReactAce stops working...

Below you can see the example, that I am trying to disable the Quill instance.

```
quillRef = React.createRef();    

componentDidMount = () => {
  console.log(this.quillRef.current.editor);

  this.quillRef.current.editor.enable(false);   // undefined
};

render () { 
    <ReactQuill
      readOnly
      value={info}
      ref={this.quillRef}
      modules={quillConfig}
    >
}
```

If you know some way to stop the ReactQuill to receive any input from the keyboard, I would be glad because I think that is causing the bug.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't really know what was problem that was causing the bug, but I took off the inner div and problem was solved. I saw this issue at the repo: https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill/issues/282 and figured out that I could do the same thing.

Answer (score 11):

in React Quill 1.3.5, you can add the readOnly prop as true. It will disable your editor like input tag when disabled.

Answer (score 5):

You can just use the `readOnly` property as the following:

```
<ReactQuilltheme="snow" readOnly={true} />
```

Of course you need to make it dynamic by using `useState()`

```
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
    
return (
    <ReactQuilltheme="snow" readOnly={disabled} />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add event listener on "keydown" and ref to ReactQuill

```
this.quillRef.current.addEventListener('keydown', null);
```